# three position on/off/on

Tags: python, internet, radio

Hi I am converting a 1963 Roberts R300 transistor radio into an internet Radio. I will be using a raspberry pi for this and as the radio has a three position on/off/on switch to choose between long wave off and medium wave, and would like to reuse that.

The idea is that the long wave position will be the Internet radio.
The off position would place the radio into standby.
The medium wave will switch to an FM module.

I have managed to get pins 16 and 18 to recognise the the switch positions but do not know how to get the pi to go into standby. I am really clueless but in my head I feel I have to get pins 16 and 18 to BOTH read false (low) to instigate the shutdown after a short delay.

Can anyone help with this please? I have absolutely no experience at this and am fumbling around. There is no info on the internet or in books that I can find where python can read 2 pins.

Thanks in advance and for your time in reading this

Joe

Comment: so, your question is not about a switch at all ... please update your post to make it about the actual problem